# Table in mySQL that has several foreign keys that are primary key, getting an error ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I had created those tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `course` (
  `idcourse` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `courseName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `subjectID` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idcourse`),
  KEY `subjectID_idx` (`subjectID`),
  CONSTRAINT `subjectID` FOREIGN KEY (`subjectID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`idsubject`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `exam` (
  `subjectID` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `courseID` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `examNumber` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subjectID`,`courseID`,`examNumber`),
  KEY `idCourse_idx` (`courseID`),
  CONSTRAINT `idCo` FOREIGN KEY (`courseID`) REFERENCES `course` (`idcourse`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `idSu` FOREIGN KEY (`subjectID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`idsubject`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `questionText` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer4` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subjetID` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `questionNumber` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `rightAnswer` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subjetID`,`questionNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `idsubject` FOREIGN KEY (`subjetID`) REFERENCES `subject` (`idsubject`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `subject` (
  `idsubject` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `subjectName` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idsubject`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

To **subject** table I add a record:

> idsubject = 02, subjectName = Mathematica

To **course** table I add a record:

> idcourse = 03, courseName = Algebra 1, subjectID = 02

To **exam** table I add a record:

> subjectID = 02, courseID = 03, examNumber = 01, duration = 180

Now, I want to create a table: **questionsinexam**

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`questionsinexam` (
  `idExamSubject` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `idExamCourse` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `idExamNumber` VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `idQuestionNumber` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  `pointsPerQuestion` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idExamSubject`, `idExamCourse`, `idExamNumber`, `idQuestionNumber`),
  INDEX `idExamCourse_idx` (`idExamCourse` ASC),
  INDEX `idExamNumber_idx` (`idExamNumber` ASC),
  INDEX `idQuestionNumber_idx` (`idQuestionNumber` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `idExamSubject`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idExamSubject`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`exam` (`subjectID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `idExamCourse`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idExamCourse`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`exam` (`courseID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `idExamNumber`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idExamNumber`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`exam` (`examNumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `idQuestionNumber`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idQuestionNumber`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`question` (`questionNumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Why I'm getting this error?

Thanks.

Comment: A foreign key points to a primary key, it cannot point to a *part of* a primary key. The PK of `exam` is `subjectID,courseID,examNumber`, so a foreign key **must** point to all 3 attributes included in the PK.

Comment: I'm doing that:
 CONSTRAINT `idExamSubject`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idExamSubject`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`exam` (`subjectID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `idExamCourse`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idExamCourse`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`exam` (`courseID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `idExamNumber`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idExamNumber`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`exam` (`examNumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

Comment: No you do not: `REFERENCES test.exam (subjectID)` <-- you are referencing one of the 3 attributes that make up the PK of `exam`.

Comment: I had finally created the table:
`PRIMARY KEY (`subjectID`,`courseID`,`examNumber`,`questionNumber`),
  KEY `questionsOfTable_idx` (`subjectID`,`questionNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `examOfTable` FOREIGN KEY (`subjectID`, `courseID`, `examNumber`) REFERENCES `exam` (`subjectID`, `courseID`, `examNumber`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `questionsOfTable` FOREIGN KEY (`subjectID`, `questionNumber`) REFERENCES `question` (`subjetID`, `questionNumber`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION`
Now I'm getting an error by add
ERROR 1452: 1452: Cannot add or update a child row:

Comment: @HoneyBadger
Thanks for your help, I understood and fixed it with your help.

Answer (score 0):

This constraint is definitely wrong:

```
CONSTRAINT `idExamSubject`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idExamSubject`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`exam` (`subjectID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

Perhaps you intend:

```
CONSTRAINT `idExamSubject`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idExamSubject`)
    REFERENCES `test`.`subject` (`subjectID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
```

Be sure that you create the target tables *before* you create the foreign key constraint.  The referred to table needs to exist first (so the engine can validate types on the columns used for the foreign key).

Comment: I'm getting the same error:
> ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: @Asaf - Do things in a different order.